# Как удалить от объекта связь с плагином?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть селектор $(".portfolio") По умолчанию после загрузки страницы проверяется ее ширина. Если она больше 540 пикс то я включаю для этого селектора работу плагина вот так:

```
$(".portfolio").niceScroll({
//параметры настройки плагина
});
```

Но как только определяется что пользователь меняет ширину браузера, мне нужно для этого селектора включить работу второго плагина, то есть что бы было так:

```
$(".portfolio").slick({});
```

Вопрос первый: как правильно называются эти конструкции что я описал? То есть все что после селектор. Название плагина и настройки

Вопрос второй, как удалить надстройку .niceScroll и включить slick?

Comment: смотри документацию плагина, наверняка есть команда типа destroy или подобная

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо большое! точно! все сработало. нашел функции для destroy у обоих плагинов.

Comment: если самостоятельно нашел решение, добавь свой собственный ответ с подробным описанием что и как